# JS: странная работа regexp

Tags: javascript

Почему регулярка /^[A-яё\s-]+$/ пропускает символы []{}^~_|     ??

Answer (score 4):

Потому что все эти символы входят в диапазон между заглавной латинской 'A' и строчной кириллической 'я'.

Comment: чтобы их избежать остается лишь использовать исключения?

Comment: @JackBauer делайте так - /[А-Яа-яёЁ]/ , или же так /[а-яё]/i